# What is the difference between git clone, git fetch and git pull?

Tags: git, github, fetch, clone, pull

Could you explain the difference between git clone, git pull and git fetch? I have read some other answers but none of them state the difference between the three clearly.

Comment: You must read the doc of git first. Git is not friendly enought for beginner. Posing a question like this is not helpful unless you read the doc. Otherwise, you may can't even understand the answers here.

Comment: Here's an intro: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1 git clone**

The clone command in git is used when you want to download an existing git repository to your local computer.

**2 git pull**

When you want to take changes or updates done by other developer/team member on git repository, you have to use git pull.

In detail git pull is the command that fetches the content from a remote repository and integrates it with the local repository/branch. It is, in actuality, a combination of git fetch and git merge called in that order.

**3 git fetch**

Git "fetch" Downloads commits, objects and refs from another repository. It fetches branches and tags from one or more repositories.

For more details study these:

1. https://git-scm.com/docs
2. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/git-push-pull